# Evitar que se vea la sección anterior al redimensionar la ventana

Tags: html, css

Tengo una página con varias secciones que ocupan todo el alto y el ancho de la pantalla, la idea es que el usuario solo vea una sección a la vez, pero al momento de redimensionar la ventana se revela parte de la sección anterior o siguiente:

```css
html, body{
  overflow:hidden;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
section{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#one{
  background-color: yellow;
}

#two{
  background-color: blue;
}

#three{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container"> 
  <section id="one">
    <h1>One</h1>
    <a href="#two">Two</a>
    <a href="#three">Three</a>
  </section>
  <section id="two">
    <a href="#one">One</a>
    <h1>Two</h1>
    <a href="#three">Three</a>
  </section>
  <section id="three">
    <a href="#one">One</a>
    <a href="#two">Two</a>
    <h1>Three</h1>
  </section>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

¿Como puedo evitar que al redimensionar la ventana se vea parte de otra sección diferente? Quiero que siempre se mantenga el foco en la sección en la que estoy actualmente (que si estoy en two y redimensiono no se vea una parte de one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dale una mirada a este código que encontré ([aquí el link](https://codepen.io/jvondoom/pen/VvbrdY)), donde se realiza un scrollTop hacia cada div objetivo, creo que el problema principal es que al realizar el resize no se tiene en cuenta el nuevo valor de height, quizá se pueda hacer como se ve en el ejemplo, con porcentajes.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('div.top').click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("div.middle").offset().top
  }, 1000)
}), 
  $('div.middle').click(function (){
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("div.bottom").offset().top
    }, 1000)
  }),
  $('div.bottom').click(function (){
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("div.top").offset().top
    }, 1000)
  })
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
}

.top {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.middle {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.bottom {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  displa
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top">
  <h1>Top</h1>
</div>
<div class="middle">
  <h1>Middle</h1>
</div>
<div class="bottom">
  <h1>Bottom</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente, funciona perfecto. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: @RaúlLara Un gusto ser de ayuda, por favor márcala como la respuesta que buscabas.